# How to find date differences in php

Tags: php, mysql, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP calculate person's current age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380990/php-calculate-persons-current-age)

I want to find the persons age.

```
 $time=$row['date_of_birth'];
 $date=explode("-", $time);//gets the date birth from the database and puts it into an array
 $a=getdate();//gets todays date
 $diff_date= gregoriantojd($a["mon"],a["mday"],a["year"] ) - gregoriantojd(date[1],date[2],date[0]);//subtracts the differences between the dates, this is returned in seconds..
```

The question is whether this is the way to do it? and how do I convert the seconds and convert them to years (as an integer)?!

EDIT:
I think that the last line should be this:

```
 return floor($diff_date /60*60*24*365);
```

Comment: return floor($diff_date /60*60*24*365); should the last line be that?

Answer (score 3):

Just try with [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) (converts date string into timestamp):

```
$time = strtotime($row['date_of_birth']);
$age  = date('Y', $time - time());

echo 'age: ' . $age;
```

Comment: will it give me an integer or a decimal?

Comment: @WithFlyingColors It will give you an integer value.

Answer (score 1):

If `$time` is supposed to be unix timestamp

```
$time=$row['date_of_birth'];
$date1 = new DateTime($time);
$date_diff = $date1->diff(new DateTime(), true);
$age = $date_diff->y;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of the [date_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) function in PHP.

Comment: dude, I want to see if my way works

Comment: if you want to see if your way works then run it and see? If not then try these answers that have been given to you.

Answer (score 0):

> 1st question: The question is whether this is the way to do it?

No.  The function gregoriantojd (per the manual entry [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gregoriantojd.php)) returns a value in days, not seconds.  I like the date_diff conversion that Piotr gives the best.

> 2nd question: how do I convert the seconds and convert them to years
> (as an integer)?!

Well, if you were starting with a number of seconds (which you aren't) then your second formula would be mostly correct, but of course it wouldn't account for leap-years.  So for anyone older than 4, or at least 8, it would be off for one or more days around their birthday.  Usually on their birthday is a pretty important time to get their age correct.